# randomForest using R for regression, make sense?

Tags: r, regression, prediction

I want to exam which variable impacts most on the outcome, in my data, which is the stock yield. My data is like below.

[image]

And my code is also attached.

```
library(randomForest)
require(data.table)
data = fread("C:/stockcrazy.csv")
PEratio <- data$offeringPE/data$industryPE
data_update <- data.frame(data,PEratio)

train <- data_update[1:47,]
test <- data_update[48:57,]
```

For the above subset data set train and test, I am not sure if I need to do a cross validation on this data. And I don't know how to do it.

```
data.model <- randomForest(yield ~ offerings + offerprice + PEratio + count + bingo 
                           + purchase , data=train, importance=TRUE)

par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
varImpPlot(data.model, n.var = 6, main = "Random Forests: Top 6 Important Variables")
importance(data.model)
plot(data.model)


model.pred <- predict(data.model, newdata=test)
model.pred

d <- data.frame(test,model.pred)
```

I am sure not sure if the result of IncMSE is good or bad. Can someone interpret this?[image]

Additionally, I found the predicted values of the test data is not a good prediction of the real data. So how can I improve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see. Let's start with %IncMSE:

I found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12605/measures-of-variable-importance-in-random-forests) really good answer on cross validated about %IncMSE which I quote:

> if a predictor is important in your current model, then assigning
>   other values for that predictor randomly but 'realistically' (i.e.:
>   permuting this predictor's values over your dataset), should have a
>   negative influence on prediction, i.e.: using the same model to
>   predict from data that is the same except for the one variable, should
>   give worse predictions.
>
> So, you take a predictive measure (MSE) with the original dataset and
>   then with the 'permuted' dataset, and you compare them somehow. One
>   way, particularly since we expect the original MSE to always be
>   smaller, the difference can be taken. Finally, for making the values
>   comparable over variables, these are scaled.

This means that in your case the most important variable is purchase i.e. when the variable purchase was permuted (i.e. the order of the values randomly changed) the resulting model was 12% worse than having the variable in its original order in terms of calculating the mean square error. The MSE was 12% higher using a permuted purchase variable meaning that the this variable is the most important. Variable importance is just a measure of how important your predictor variables were in the model you used. In your case purchase was the most important and P/E ratio was the least (for those 6 variables). This is not something you can interpret as good or bad because it doesn't show you how well the model fits unseen data. I hope this is clear now.

For the cross-validation:

You do not need to do a cross validation during the training phase because it happens automatically. Approximately, 2/3 of the records are used for the creation of a tree and the 1/3 that is left out (out-of-bag data) is used to assess the tree afterwards (the R squared for the tree is computed using the oob data)

As for the improvement of the model:

By showing just the 10 first lines of the predicted and the actual values of yield, you cannot make a safe decision on whether the model is good or bad. What you need is a test of fitness. The most common one is the R squared. It is simplistic but for comparing models and getting a first opinion about your model it does its job. This is calculated by the model for every tree that you make and can be accessed by data.model$rsq. This ranges from 0 to 1 with 1 being the perfect model and 0 showing really poor fit ( it can sometimes even take negative values which shows a bad fit). If your rsq is bad then you can try the following to improve your model although it is not certain that you will get the results you wish for:

1. Calibrate your trees in a different way.  Change the number of trees grown and prune the trees by specifying a big nodesize number. (here you use the default 500 trees and a nodesize of 5 which might overfit your model.)
2. Increase the number of variables if possible.
3. Choose a different model. There are cases were a random Forest would not work well

Comment: thanks for your comments and help. but I am still confused with the whole process. can send me an email to my email so that we can discuss that in more detail?

Comment: ,you mentioned the rsq in your post, I saw a lot of online tutorial using NMSE for both the training and testing data. What is the difference of these two?And there I haven't use 500 ntree and the nodesize for regression is 5 not 1. I am doing a regression instead of classification.

Comment: The NMSE and the MSE are exactly the same thing. The only difference is that NMSE is normalized. The normalization happens by dividing by the product of the mean observed values and the mean predicted values. an alternative is normalization by just the mean observed values (ybar). I know that you are running a regression rf and this is why I suggest using the R squared. In the above you are using ntrees = 500 because this is the default value and you are right nodesize is 5. I changed that above.

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with some of the above I would suggest [this](http://www.amazon.com/Machine-Learning-R-Brett-Lantz/dp/1782162143) book which gives you a great intro to both machine learning and R.

Comment: I will also add an answer about cross validation. I had missed that part

Comment: The result of data.model$rsq is a matrix, there are both negative and positive value.

Comment: Yes. the result is actually a vector not a matrix of length(data.model$rsq)=ntree. so in your case that is 500. the k-th element of the vector is the R squared calculated for the k first trees. Therefore, the last element in the vector shows the total R squared for the random forest based on the oob records of the training set. As a rule of thumb if that last element is negative or close to zero then your model does not fit the data well enough.

Comment: my result for the train data is : Mean of squared residuals: 872.1524, % Var explained: 16.5. It seems not good, right?

Comment: The Mean of squared residuals on its own does not say much (although the closer to zero the better the model). it is used to compare different models. If you create a new model with a smaller MSE then you can say that it is a better model. %Var explained is a good measure of the fit of the model on its own. How good it is you can never say for sure. 16.5% is not the best you can get but it is definitely better than chance so it is something. There is always a limit to how well you can predict given your predictors. If for example this limit is 20% then you have a great model. I hope this helps

Comment: One thing confused me now is that which data I should use for finding the rsq, the train or the full data? I know I should use the full data to see the variable importance.

Comment: Well, what I always do which is supposed to be the general practice is: use just the train set to get the rsq from the data.model$rsq vector and but then also use the test set to evaluate your model on completely unseen data. i.e. use the function predict to make predictions for the test set and then calculate the rsq using the rsquared function from the misctools package like [here](http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/comparing-random-forests-in-python-and-r.html)

Comment: hi, I have a new question, since the most important variable is the yield var, but it could be dynamic, which means that for some stocks, that value would change. So how can I do this case?

Comment: yield is not the most important variable. purchase is the most important variable.yield is what you are trying to predict. I dont really get the question.

Comment: what I mean is that some values of yield is likely to be changed over time, should I use those yield obs?

Comment: an observation is supposed to be a snapshot of time. you need to choose the yield that corresponds to all the other variables you have at a specific time. If the yield changes you can also include that but as a new observation with a new set of variables.

Comment: for one stock, the highest price might change, so the yield will change as well, but all the other variables will remain, like PE, Offering shares.

Comment: This is a question for a financial expert maybe then. This depends on which variables you need to choose for the model and how these interact among themselves. Maybe there is a financial exchange site where you could ask that. For me I would choose what I have at the moment and not care about the change of price in the future.

Comment: ,hi, I rerun the data. and my result is r2 <- rSquared(test$yield, test$yield - predict(data.model, newdata=test)), which is -0.534802, this is bad, right?

Comment: unfortunately, yeah it is bad.